# How to normalize coloring of data with seaborn in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, pandas-styles

I got data like you can see in picture 1, because I have value 0 and rest is much bigger (values are between 0 and 100). I would like to get data like is show in picture 2. How to solve this problem?

This is minimal reproducible code.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import colors
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[2019, 2020], [1, 2]],
                                   names=['year', 'visit'])
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3'], ['value1', 'value2']],
                                     names=['subject', 'type'])

data = np.round(np.random.randn(4, 6), 1)
data[:, ::2] *= 20
data += 50

rdata = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

cc = sns.light_palette("red", as_cmap=True)
cc.set_bad('white')

def my_gradient(s, cmap):
    return [f'background-color: {colors.rgb2hex(x)}'
            for x in cmap(s.replace(np.inf, np.nan))]
       

styler = rdata.style
red = styler.apply(
        my_gradient,
        cmap=cc, 
        subset=rdata.columns.get_loc_level('value1', level=1)[0],
        axis=0)

styler
```

Picture 1

[image]

Picture 2

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to normalize. Usually, in matplotlib, a [norm](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/colors/colormapnorms.html) is used, of which [`plt.Normalize()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.colors.Normalize.html#matplotlib.colors.Normalize) is the most standard one.

The updated code could look like:

```py
my_norm = plt.Normalize(0, 100)

def my_gradient(s, cmap):
    return [f'background-color: {colors.rgb2hex(x)}'
            for x in cmap(my_norm(s.replace(np.inf, np.nan)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can normalize you data with the following equation (x-min)/(max-min). So to apply this to your dataframe you could use something like the following:

```
result = pd.DataFrame()
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    hold = {}
    for h in df:
        hold[h] = (row[h]-df[h].min())/(df[h].max()-df[h].min())
    result = result.append(hold,ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Where do I put numbers 0 and 100?

Comment: This will normalize your whole dataframe by column. So the dataframe would contain numbers 0-100 although it could really have any number in them.